# How can I move the tabs bar to the bottom of the window with a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I need for my extension to move the bar with tabs (a `<toolbar>` element with ID `TabsToolbar`) to the bottom of the window, under the `#browser` `<hbox>` element.

I know how to add and modify elements with extensions, but I'm not sure how to place an existing element somewhere else in the page with an overlay. What is the proper way to do this?

UPDATE:

I found another add on that does this among other things, called https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/.

It appears that when tabs are set to the bottom, this plug adds an empty `<toolbox>` element with id `tabmix-bottom-toolbox` below the `#browser` `<hbox>` element. Even though the tabs appear on the bottom, the actual tab XUL markup is still in it's regular place inside the `TabsToolbar` `<toolbar>` element at the top.

I think what the author does is:

1. Insert a XUL placeholder element under the browser area, and set the placeholder to the height of the TabsToolbar.
2. Then give TabsToolbar a fixed position via css, and
3. Set the "top" property based on the offset of the placeholder.

I haven't confirmed this yet by trying it in my own plug-in though. I've also found that absolute positioning does wonky things in XUL.

Comment: "Firefox", not "FireFox"... Not a big deal, just saying ;)

Comment: I found an addon (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) that lets you put tabs on the bottom, among many other things. I'm trying to wade through the code to see if I can figure out where and how the author does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might give the following a shot:

1. Insert a hbox (lets say with id bottom-tabs-container) before vbox with id "browser-bottombox"
2. In javascript, use something like

   ```
   var tabsToolbar = document.getElementById("TabsToolbar");
   document.getElementById("bottom-tabs-container").appendChild(tabsToolbar);
   ```

This should retain any event handlers that were bound already. However note that you might break a lot of appearance related stuff.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. The tab mix plug-in I referenced above uses absolute positioning and events to re-size on window create/re-size. This seems like a better option.